# raspberry pi: no internet email and mysql connection

Tags: python, mysql, email

I have made a program on a raspberry pi that takes inputs from multiple sensors and sends that data out via emails and up to a remote mysql database.

The problem is that if the device loses internet for what ever reason it crashes the code. Is there a way to tell python that if it fails, try again in so many seconds and loop around until it gets reconnected?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using [try and except](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It crashes the code" isn't a very helpful description of what goes wrong (better to say that a particular piece of code produces a specific error message). So I am assuming that an `smtplib.SMTP` object's `sendmail()` method is raising an `smtplib.SMTPException` or some subclass thereof.

The trick is to catch the exception and retry, but you shouldn't really do this forever. You probably need something like

```
import smtplib
    ...
sender = smtplib.SMTP(...)
    ...
retry_count = 10
done = False
while not done:
    sender.sendmail(...)
    done = True
except smtplib.SMTPException:
    if retry_count:
        retry_count -= 1
    else:
        raise <some exception you can catch in surrounding code if necessary>
```

You may also want to put a `time.sleep()` call in where you decrement the retry count, as an immediate retry is unlikely to be successful.

If the exception is something more basic like a socket timeout error you may need to catch that instead.

Comment: All new to this but your was very informative. Thank you